# HTML/CSS Same size no matter text

Tags: html, css

Hey I need help with section's, how to make section size unchangeable no matter text size. Photo:

[image]

I want that both section would be the same size as in left no matter text size. Here is CSS

```
#info2 {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-top: 0.1%;
}
#info3 {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create add a class to the sections you want the same and call it something like sectionHeight. Then create css setting its height.

For example;

**HTML**

```
<div class="sectionHeight" id="info2"></div>
<div class="sectionHeight" id="info3"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#info2 {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-top: 0.1%;
}
#info3 {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}   

. sectionHeight {
    height:20%
    }
```